# Pyspark - how to drop records by primary keys?

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to delete the records from an `old_df` if a `new_df` has a `del` flag for the key `metric_id`. What is the right way to achieve this?

old_df (flag here is filled with nulls on purpose)

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
|metric_id| flag   |        value|
+---------+--------+-------------+
|       10|    null|       value2|
|       10|    null|       value9|
|       12|    null|updated_value|
|       15|    null|  test_value2|
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

new_df

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
|metric_id| flag   |        value|
+---------+--------+-------------+
|       10|     del|       value2|
|       12|    pass|updated_value|
|       15|     del|  test_value2|
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

result_df

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
|metric_id| flag   |        value|
+---------+--------+-------------+
|       12|    pass|updated_value|
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to join then filter:

```
result_df = (
      old_df.join(new_df, on='metric_id', how='left')
            .where((new_df['flag'].isNull()) | (new_df['flag'] != lit('del')))
            .select('metric_id', new_df['flag'], new_df['value'])
)
```

Which produces

```
+---------+----+-------------+
|metric_id|flag|        value|
+---------+----+-------------+
|       12|pass|updated_value|
+---------+----+-------------+
```

I'm using a `left` join because there might be records in `old_df` for which the primary key is not present in `new_df` (and you don't want to delete those).